# Upgrade from windows 8.1 VOLUME_MAK channel to Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows-8.1, upgrade, windows-10

[image]

I have a windows 8.1 enterprise install on my laptop (work computer) and want to be able to upgrade to windows 10 without having to do a full reinstall. The version i have installed is a volume licensed version but i do have a product key for standard retail windows 8 enterprise.

How would I go about doing an in place upgrade without having to get an update from the microsoft partner network?

Comment: I am marking this thread as off-topic . Stack Overflow is for Programming / Code related issues. You can ask your question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volume License version (KMS, MAK) are not accepted by the free upgrade to Windows 10. You need a valid volume license for Windows 10 Enterprise and upgrade via ISO/DVD, run `setup.exe` and select `Upgrade`. Here you can keep all applications + files.